# (MacOS) disable codesign check / run codesign on multiple files

Tags: automation, macos

so I have two questions, I'll try to keep it short (**also, im a noob**):

1. I run logic pro x and other software to make music, and some third party plugins make program crash if they get a:

   > Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)

   I can solve this problem by `codesign -f -s - (file)` but I'd rather not. Is there a way to disable code signature check so it won't even give me an error and won't check it?

*I assume the answer is no and therefore my second question:*

2. I need to run `sudo codesign -f -s -` on a `.bundle` file that's inside a `Resource` folder inside a `.component` (a package), and I have *a lot* of these to go through, for example:

   ```
   Plugin_2.component -> Resources -> **Plugin_2.bundle**  
   Plugin_3.component -> Resources -> **Plugin_3.bundle**
   ```

   is there a way to make a command to do it automatically?

   I was thinking maybe in automator? something to make it do these 2 steps:

   1. look for a `.bundle` file inside a `Resource` folder in a package
   2. run `sudo codesign -f -s -` on it

   Is that possible? maybe make it in automator and add it to Services in the right click menu? or to make it scan a whole folder with `.component`?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: for help with commandline scripting, you can ask on Superuser or Unix

Comment: It should be possible to just remove the signature on the main executable, which contains the `library-validation` flag which is what enforces the signature check on plugins. Once that flag is gone, plugins should no longer be validated.

Answer (score 1):

after some trial and error i managed to solve it easily with the following command in terminal

```
find . -name "*.bundle" -execdir sudo codesign -f -s - {} \;
```

`find . -name "*.EXTENSION"` is responsible for finding the certain file extension in a directory

`-execdir YOUR COMMAND {} \;` is responsible to executing the command.
using `-execdir` -> on the results of the previous find command ( `{}` )

fairly simple after all, hope this can help someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

Check out this script I made, it takes care of your **ENTIRE** plugin folder. Helps on fresh OS installs for sure.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/

find . -name "*.bundle" -execdir sudo xattr -cr \;
find . -name "*.VST" -execdir sudo xattr -cr \;
find . -name "*.vst3" -execdir sudo xattr -cr \;
find . -name "*.component" -execdir sudo xattr -cr \;
find . -name "*.dpm" -execdir sudo xattr -cr \;

find . -name "*.bundle" -execdir sudo codesign -f -s - {} \;
find . -name "*.VST" -execdir sudo codesign -f -s - {} \;
find . -name "*.vst3" -execdir sudo codesign -f -s - {} \;
find . -name "*.component" -execdir sudo codesign -f -s - {} \;
find . -name "*.dpm" -execdir sudo codesign -f -s - {} \;
```

Useful as it is, it could use some improvement. I would like to further expand this script to include clearing/setting permissions to allow for this to work. With my current knowledge of how this works, you have tp use a tool like Batchmod to set permissions for each individual file, tediously, then running this script afterwards.

If anyone comes across this in the future, feel free to contribute.